# How to create a new Pandas dataframe column from other columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a list of activities, *popular_activities*, as follows:

```
['google.co.uk', 'whatsapp', 'sharelatex.com', 'Financial Times', 'other',                 
'en.wikipedia.org', 'Instagram for Android', 'YouTube for Android', 
'arxiv-sanity.com', 'quora.com', 'microsoft word', 'Inbox by Gmail', 
'Google Chrome for Android', 'youtube.com', 'mendeley desktop', 
'web.whatsapp.com', 'Preview', 'texshop', 'Google Now', 'mobile - 
com.compassnews.app', 'netflix.com', 'WhatsApp Messenger Android', 'Facebook 
for Android', 'arxiv.org']
```

I also have a DataFrame as follows:

```
                       Activity                           Time Spent (seconds)
Date                                                                       
2017-03-25T00:05:00    [netflix.com, other, Google Now]   [30, 6, 2]
2017-03-25T00:10:00    [netflix.com]                      [300]
2017-03-25T00:15:00    [netflix.com]                      [102]   
2017-03-25T00:30:00    [netflix.com]                      [232]   
2017-03-25T00:35:00    [netflix.com]                      [279]
```

I would like to create a new column in this DataFrame 'Activity_vector' such that every element in this column is a vector of length equal to that of *popular_activities* where the corresponding index of the activity (as is in the *popular_activities* array) contains the time spent on that activity.

So, for example, for the second element at Date: 2017-03-25T00:05:00, the corresponding element in the new column 'Activity_vector' would be

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0]
```

such that 'Activity' netflix.com which has a corresponding 'Time Spent (seconds)' value of 30 and index 21 in *popular_activities* will have an array with index 21 filled with value 30, 'Activity' other will have it's corresponding index (4) filled with value 6, and similarly for Google Now.

A snippet of what I have is below, where self.clean_df is the DataFrame discussed:

```
class Clean_DF(object):
....
    def clean_data(self, time_percentage):
    ....
        self.clean_df['Activity_vector'] = self.clean_df.apply(lambda x: self.activity_to_vector(x),axis=1)

    def activity_to_vector(self, row):
        vect = np.zeros(len(self.popular_apps))
        for x,y in zip(row['Activity'], row['Time Spent (seconds)']):
            vect[self.popular_apps_dict[x]] += vect[self.popular_apps_dict[x]] + y
        return vect
```

However, when I run this I get the following error

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3862, 24), indices imply (3862, 2)
```

How can I go about addressing this error/writing a function that solves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
num = len(popular_activities)

def make_array(s):
    z = [0] * num
    time = s['Time Spent (seconds)']
    for i, val in enumerate(s['Activity']):
        idx = popular_activity.index(val)
        z[idx] = time[i]
    return z

df.apply(make_array, axis=1)
```